# Unable to recover data from DB2 Backup files

Tags: db2, aix, db2-luw

I have a couple of DB2 Backup files as shared with us.

I am unable to recover the data using the DB2 recover command which I used as -

```
db2 restore db <db-name> from . taken at 20151229234633
```

Got the following error for the above command.

> SQL2071N  An error occurred while accessing the shared library
>   "/resgrp463/db2inst3/db2inst3/NODE0000/SQL00001/4371/libdb2compr.a".
>   Reason code: "2".

I then modified the Recover command and added another parameter by providing compress library option as mentioned in the following command -

```
db2 restore db <db-name> from <location> taken at 20151229234633 comprlib /resgrp463/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64/libdb2compr.a
```

It gave the error as mentioned below.

> SQL2079N  An error was reported by the shared library "libdb2compr.a".
>   Return code: "104".

Any help on how to resolve it or any concrete proof specifying that the Backup File is corrupt would be appreciated.

OS Version - AIX 7.1 TL4

DB2 Version - DB2 9.7

Fix Packs Tried - GA, 1, 11 (Target side)

At the source side, we don't know the exact Fix Pack used but the version is confirmed as DB2 9.7 using the db2ckbkp header information which provides release code as D00.

Please view the db2diag log at https://pastebin.com/X8sYELNT

Upon using the command to check the backup's, I get an error as mentioned below.

Command used -

```
db2ckbkp *
```

It gave the error as

> Buffers processed:  #ERROR:  Decompression library not initialized
>
> ERROR: Failed to verify media header. Cannot continue.

Comment: Edit the question to specify the AIX version and technology-level, and also add what entries get added to db2diag when the Restore fails.   Also, please add the Db2 version+fixpack of the *source* Db2-instance (where the backup was taken), and the *target* Db2-instance where you are performing the restore.

Comment: To verify the backup image use db2ckbkp , refer to the Documentation online for your Db2-version for details.

Comment: @mao I have mentioned the details, please have a look.

Comment: For this symptom, It's essential that you know the Db2 fixpack level at both sides(source and target). I recall a previous occurrence of this symptom at one site, possibly fixed by ensuring the same compression library binary was used both ends.  As this was done via IBM support, you should open a support-ticket with IBM if you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

All three error messages are related to a db2 library which db2 restore command needs as shown at each error messages. There is a problem at db2 restore command executing machine/box, client side and not server side. And this type of situation can be occurred when:
   1) db2 restore related file(s) is corrupted, such as the library file in message
   2) db2 restore unexpectedly reads the library file by miss configuration

For 1), it may be fixed by:
   install product again or create a new instance.  this will place normal file(s).
   
For 2), it may be fixed by:
   find out what was changed at the environment then fix.  this will pick up correct library file.

For your information.  End of support for V9.7 is September 30, 2017 as show below:
**Recommended Fix Packs for DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/recommended-fix-packs-db2-linux-unix-and-windows

Hope this helps.